# Check for existence of an element in the collection c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to prevent adding an item in the list that already exist in C#. The code below loops through datatable rows.
As you can see  rows is of the type `List<CubeReportRow>`

datatables rows does contain duplicates. I need check if the rowName in the datatable is already in rows object of type `List<CubeReportRow>`. Please see the condition that i have set in the foreach loop. When I try to check by rowname its says cannot convert string to type CubeReportRow. If I check  if (!rows.Contains(row[0])),there is no compile error but i doesn't work. How do I check for its existence in the rows collection.

Class CubeReportRow

```
 public class CubeReportRow
    {
        public string RowName { get; set; }
        public string RowParagraph { get; set; }
        public int ReportSection { get; set; }
    }
```

C# Method

```
 public virtual IList<CubeReportRow> TransformResults(CubeReport report,DataTable dataTable)
        {
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0 || dataTable.Columns.Count == 0)
                return new List<CubeReportRow>();

            var rows = new List<CubeReportRow>();
            var columns = columnTransformer.GetColumns(dataTable);

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                
                var rowName = row[0].ToString();
                if (!rows.Contains(rowName))
                {
                    var values =
                        cubeReportValueFactory.CreateCubeReportValuesForRow(dataTable, row, rowName, columns, report);

                    var reportRow = new CubeReportRow(row[3].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), values);
                    rows.Add(reportRow);
                }
            }

            return rows;
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your `CubeReportRow`. Does having the same `RowName` property value have the semantics of _Equals_

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Dictionary<string, CubeReportRow>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) for your `rows` variable  and check if key (`rowName`) exists with [`ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-5.0):

```
var rows = new Dictionary<string, CubeReportRow>();
if (!rows.ContainsKey(rowName))
{
    // ...
    rows.Add(rowName, reportRow);
}

// ...

return rows.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: The only issue is in this case you will get last-in, whereas with `! contains` you will get first-in.

Comment: If you check whether a collection contains a property, then the FIRST one is added and subsequent are not. if you use the dictionary, adding same key multiple times overwrites the first value so you get the LAST one.

Comment: @Zer0 nice point, so perhaps this is the best solution after all :)

Comment: @zaitsman Yeah I retract my comment because `TryAdd` isn't going to work without the value, and OP is skipping value creation if the key exists.  I just have muscle memory to spot `Contains` then `Add`.  This answer also takes performance into consideration.

Comment: @zaitsman the logic is the same - use `ContainsKey` to check if something with the same `rowName` is present - if not - add a new one, so result should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer as I believe [Guru Strons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) answer is sufficient.

However, there are a bunch of ways to do this which will yield different performance and complexity depending on your data / duplicate ratio (and not limited to the following).

**Dictionary**

```
var rows = new Dictionary<string, CubeReportRow>();
foreach (var dataRow in _data)
   if (!rows.ContainsKey(dataRow.RowName))
      rows.Add(dataRow.RowName, dataRow);
return rows.Values.ToList();
```

**HashSet**

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(_data.Length);
return _data.Where(x => hashSet.Add(x.RowName)).ToList();
```

**GroupBy**

```
return _data.GroupBy(x => x.RowName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

**IEqualityComparer**

```
public class SomeComparer : IEqualityComparer<CubeReportRow> {
   public bool Equals(CubeReportRow x, CubeReportRow y) {
      return x.RowName == y.RowName;
   }
   public int GetHashCode(CubeReportRow obj) {
      return obj.RowName.GetHashCode();
   }
}

...

return _data.Distinct(new SomeComparer()).ToList();
```

## Benchmarks

**Config**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19041.746 (2004/?/20H1)
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU 3.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.102
  [Host]        : .NET Core 5.0.2 (CoreCLR 5.0.220.61120, CoreFX 5.0.220.61120), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET Core 5.0 : .NET Core 5.0.2 (CoreCLR 5.0.220.61120, CoreFX 5.0.220.61120), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET Core 5.0  Runtime=.NET Core 5.0
```

**Results**

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dictionary | 205.3 us | 4.06 us | 5.69 us |
| HashSet | 237.6 us | 4.73 us | 10.19 us |
| Distinct | 299.4 us | 5.24 us | 4.90 us |
| GroupBy | 451.3 us | 5.28 us | 4.68 us |

**Full Test Code**

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp50)]
public class Test
{
   private CubeReportRow[] _data;


   public class CubeReportRow
   {
      public string RowName { get; set; }
      public string RowParagraph { get; set; }
      public int ReportSection { get; set; }
   }

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void Setup()
   {
      var r = new Random(32);
      _data = new CubeReportRow[10000];
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
         _data[i] = new CubeReportRow() {RowName = r.Next(100).ToString()};

   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<CubeReportRow> Dictionary()
   {
      var rows = new Dictionary<string, CubeReportRow>();
      foreach (var dataRow in _data)
         if (!rows.ContainsKey(dataRow.RowName))
            rows.Add(dataRow.RowName, dataRow);
      return rows.Values.ToList();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<CubeReportRow> HashSet()
   {
      var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(_data.Length);
      return _data.Where(x => hashSet.Add(x.RowName)).ToList();

   }

   public class SomeComparer : IEqualityComparer<CubeReportRow>
   {
      public bool Equals(CubeReportRow x, CubeReportRow y)
      {
         return x.RowName == y.RowName;
      }

      public int GetHashCode(CubeReportRow obj)
      {
         return obj.RowName.GetHashCode();
      }
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<CubeReportRow> Distinct()
   {
      return _data.Distinct(new SomeComparer()).ToList();

   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<CubeReportRow> GroupBy()
   {
      return _data.GroupBy(x => x.RowName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

   }
}
```

Note : If you are interested in performance, run these benchmarks yourself with realistic data.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is perfect for this (in terms of easy-to-read code)

At the top of the file:
`using System.Linq;`

Then:
`if (!rows.Any(r => r.RowName == rowName))`  (replace `if (!rows.Contains(rowName))`)

Comment: @GuruStron Nope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.contains?view=net-5.0

Comment: His return type is `IList` and he did not mention `LINQ`. Regardless, the Contains you linked requires a full object passed in and will be evaluated using `.Equals()` but what OP needs is a comparison by first column in his data row.

Comment: I am getting error at line r[0] . Cannot apply indexing to expression of type CubeReportRow

Comment: @Tom apologies, change to `r.RowName` (see my edit)

Comment: It might be this   if (!rows.Any(r => r.RowName == rowName))

Comment: This works, and is easy to read and understand.  However I'll note this could be as slow as O(N) where a dictionary could be as fast as O(1).  `Any` needs to enumerate `rows`.  The bigger `rows` gets the slower this solution gets.